# manage imageviews when set visability

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

**manage imageview when set visability**

**i know its hard to get my problem i tried to explain that i could**

**Explanation:**

First of all i have 4 `imageviews` in for the first time only 2 `imageviews` are visible to user. When user clicks on one of them gallery open and user pick image and i set picked image to visible imageview then i make visible another imageview which is at the same position of the firstimageview and i take this recently visible image to front (using bring to front ..in built method).... but when i do that what happens u can see in problematic image link....

**note**

The image link i have added as output there in two different images are has white borders maybe its not been seeing in image.

**Explanation Added**

I have 4 imageviews in 2 different linearlayouts with parent linearlayout
but i failed to manage with their visibility

**Problem**

Imageview sets beside a first imageview when i set(but i has to be over first image ) see snap of problem to understand perfectly

Problematic output:

[image: problematic output]

Output i want:

[image: output i want]

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/back"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/frame2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/rect_2"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/frame2_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/rect_2"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/frame3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/rect_2"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/frame3_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/rect_2"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/frame2"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:padding="5dp"
             android:src="@drawable/rect_2"
             android:visibility="visible" />

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/frame2_1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="0dp"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:padding="5dp"
             android:src="@drawable/rect_2"
             android:visibility="gone" />

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/frame3"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:padding="5dp"
             android:src="@drawable/rect_2" />

         <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/frame3_1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:scaleType="matrix"
             android:src="@drawable/frame_sq"
             android:visibility="gone" />-->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**java file**

```
if (requestCode == frm1 && data != null) {
  Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
  String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};
  Cursor cursor = managedQuery(selectedImageUri, projection, null, null, null);
  int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
  BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
  final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;
  int scale = 1;
  while (options.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && options.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
    scale *= 2;
    options.inSampleSize = scale;
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
    frame2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    Bitmap b2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.rect_2);
    frame2_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    frame2_1.setImageBitmap(b2);
    frame2_1.bringToFront();
    frame2.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    frame2_1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    frame2.setOnTouchListener(new Touch());
    dialog.dismiss();
  }
```

**needed code i have posted over here**

Comment: Didn't get your question..Elaborate it perfectly..

Comment: @OnkarNene did u see two images ?

Comment: @OnkarNene first of all i have four imageviews in for the first time only two imageviews are visible to user ...when user click on one of them gallery open and user pick image and i set picked image to visible imageview then i make visible another imageview which is at the same position of the firstimageview and i take this recently visible image to front (using bring to front ..in built method).... but when i do that what happens u can see in problematic image link....